# How to refresh a div?

Tags: javascript, html, visualforce

Most of the examples I have found explain how to refresh a div with text or with another page. I just want to reload the div again after click on a button. How can I do this using javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh a div, you want to place new content in the div? If so, it could be as easy as changing the innerHTML contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AJAX.

If you use jQuery, it's as simple as `$('#mydiv').load(url)`

Answer (score 2):

Any change to the DIV element is stored in the DOM of the page is displayed immediately. You do not need to do anything for that. However, the old state of the DIV after the change is lost. You need to store it somewhere and setup it again to make it visible.

Comment: Thanks Kirill. Do you have any example of how can I store it and then place it again?

Comment: Maybe the simplest way is to create an invisible DIV `<div style="display:none"> ... <div>` and store the value there?

Answer (score 0):

Please call a ajax function on click of the button and set the innerHTML property of the div with return result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So we just place this little JS code snippet into our page to refresh everything inside the tag with the content id, let’s say every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").load(location.href,"");
}, 5000);
```