# How to refresh a table with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I search about my question online and found this closest to my query. 
[How to refresh a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448791/how-to-refresh-a-div)

But I am still unable to find the solution of my query. My query is I have below code

```
    <h1>Time</h1> 
    <input type="text" value="0.0" id="time">
    <button id="FormSubmit">Submit</button>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
    <table id="responds" >
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY time");
            //get all records from add_delete_record table
            while($array = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            <tr id="item_<?php echo $array["id"] ?>">
                    <td><?php echo $array['time']?>
                    <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-<?php echo $array["id"] ?>">
                        <img src="icon_del.gif" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
    </table>
```

and I want to reload this table again after every 30 seconds. I am pretty naive in using jquery and also I don't have any script file to get data from server. I don't want to put database code in other files due to some other reasons. How can I do this?

Below is some code that is related with table.

```
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if($("#time").val()==='') {
                    alert("Please enter some text!");
                    return false;
                }   
                $("#FormSubmit").hide(); 
                $("#LoadingImage").show(); 

                var myData = 'content_txt='+ $("#time").val(); 
                jQuery.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "time.php", 
                    dataType:"text", 
                    data:myData, 
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#responds").append(response);
                        $("#contentText").val(''); 
                        $("#FormSubmit").show(); 
                        $("#LoadingImage").hide(); 

                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        $("#FormSubmit").show(); 
                        $("#LoadingImage").hide(); 
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            });

            $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); 
                var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; 
                var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; 

                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); 
                $(this).hide(); 

                jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "time.php", 
        dataType:"text", 
        data:myData, 
        success:function(response){ 
                        $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
                        alert(thrownError);
        }
                });
            });
```

Comment: You can using AJAX to display table. With this solution you can set how to AJAX run. And anything.

Comment: If you want to reload the table again using the same php script, you have to use AJAX as indicated in that link.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) or [Kendo UI Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)

Comment: You need to put the table part in a separate file (`table.php` for example)m then, you need to `include table.php;` using PHP on the root document. Next, use [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and call the `table.php` script in the _url_ parameter and [replace the table with](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) the updated HTML

Comment: Looks like I have to update question

Comment: See code now please thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return make the `time.php`to return a JSON with the collection of the items in the table:

```
// Append the following to time.php
$data = array();
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY time");
//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($array = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $array['id'], 'time' => $array['time']);
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Then, call this script:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "time.php", 
    dataType:"json",  // INSTEAD OF text
    data: {
         content_txt: $("#time").val()
    }, 
    success:function(response) {
        var $table = $("#responds").html('<tr><th>Time</th></tr>'); // RESET THE TABLE
        for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            // Append the new rows to the table, based on the data returned from the server
            $table.append('<tr id="item_' + response[i].id + '>' +
                '<td>' + response[i].time + '>' +
                    '<a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-' + response[i].id + '>' +
                        '<img src="icon_del.gif" />' +
                    '</a>' +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>');
        }
        // The following lines are commented-out because this runs in the background and only update the content of the table
        // $("#contentText").val(''); 
        // $("#FormSubmit").show(); 
        // $("#LoadingImage").hide(); 
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $("#FormSubmit").show(); 
        $("#LoadingImage").hide(); 
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

You can put this script inside [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and run it every 30 seconds (Interval is in milliseconds so it should be 30000):

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  // The above code goes here 
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Ahh looks like everything is fine, but how will I update this table every 30 seconds?

Comment: Table is reloaded but there was no content

Comment: I am getting fine response at this line `for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {` because I alert response.length but table content is not showing

Comment: and page source is showing content. I cannot believe this.  HTML have content but is not showing

Answer (score 1):

You could update the results of your html table with AJAX, like so:

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller.php",  //php controller fecthing the info
            data: {
                param1: p1,
                param2: p2         // controller params               
            },            
            success: function(data) {                    
                if (data != null){
                  $("#yourTableID").html(data);   //update table html
                }else{
                  alert('No results found!');
                }
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save the contents of the table in a separate php file:

```
    // tablebody.php
    //
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY time");
        //get all records from add_delete_record table
        while($array = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr id="item_<?php echo $array["id"] ?>">
                <td><?php echo $array['time']?>
                <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-<?php echo $array["id"] ?>">
                    <img src="icon_del.gif" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
```

then in your html file you can then use jquery to load that file into the table:

```
<table id="responds">
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#responds").load("tablebody.php");
    });
</script>
```

You may have to restructure your code a little in order to use this method effectively but it will solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot save table in other php file

Comment: Can you store it in a string and use eval()?

Comment: Wait I am updating question